# wget: can't execute 'openssl': No such file or directory

Tags: openssl, wget

error got while executing the following

```
wget https://182.72.194.130:8443/device_mgr/device-mgmt/app/cnc/sno/SCNC12J002/updates?cur_fw_ver=1.1\(0\)7\&cur_config_ver=1.0 --no-check-certificate
```

error :   wget: can't execute 'openssl': No such file or directory

How it can be avoided? why no-check-certificate is not working? Iam using below busy box version
BusyBox v1.23.1

Answer (score 0):

The wget version included with BusyBox does not support SSL. You can try to use the 'real' wget or curl.

Answer (score -1):

you can download openssl and after install , set openssl envoirement in

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).